# Crear objeto tipo DATE con formato "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS"

Tags: java, sql, hql

Veréis, tengo en BBDD el registro fecha el cual la almacena con el siguiente formato, ejemplo: "2019-01-18 14:33:34.0".

Para obtener por ejemplo una fecha inicial, tengo el siguiente código:

```
 private Date getFechaInicial() {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
            Date initialDate = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());

            return initialDate;
        }
```

El cual me devuelve la fecha en el siguiente formato: "Mon Jan 28 23:59:59 CET 2019".

Mi problema es que quiero realizar desde java, una consulta HQL a la BBDD comparando que una fecha dada sea mayor que una en BBDD, lo cual no soy capaz ya que los formatos, aún siendo DATE, no son iguales.

¿Alguna pista de cómo podría hacerlo? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar la libreria de LocalDateTime. Es una libreria de tiempo de Java 8 y superior que es bastante superior a Date y genera las fechas en formatos compatibles con SQL.

Para generar una hora libre actual solo ha que hacer:

```
LocalDateTime desde = LocalDateTime.now();
```

Aquí tienes la información de la api

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html

Date como tal no es lo mas aconsejable para usar, y esta api es muy muy sencilla, te la recomiendo si tienes que trabajar con fechas y horas

(LocalDate es sin horas, solo las fechas)

Answer (score 0):

1. En java, los `Date` y `Calendar` no tienen "formato". Representan un instante en el tiempo (p.ej. `java.util.Date` solo es un *wrapper* sobre un long que representa los milisegundos desde 01/01/1970.

   Cuando haces `toString()` te da una representación en String de ese valor, pero no es la única. Puedes usar la clase `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` para escoger tu propio formato. Por ejemplo "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".
2. Si en la BD el campo con el que comparas es de fecha, lo que toca es que hagas la comparación como fechas y no como Strings, pero no das información al respecto.

Comment: Efectivamente, el campo en BD está en formato fecha, por lo que no me sirve el convertir en String ya que no podría comparar que una sea mayor o menor que otra.